# postgres_ext/serializers help... seems so simple, but can't get anything to work as described

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel, serialization

https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext-serializers

this seems so simple to setup, but I can't seem to get any basic functionality to work in terms of moving the JSON from rails to postgres. I tried including the following in my ams init, in my specific serializers and in my models, but it never seems to be activating.

I'm on Rails 4.2.3 and Ruby 2.2

and this is what I've tried adding to multiple files:

> require 'postgres_ext/serializers'

Really appreciate your help, I know I must be missing something obvious.

**Update:** To give a bit more context, it you read the README.md instructions for this gem, it just says"

> Just require 'postgres_ext/serializers' and use
>   ActiveModel::Serializers as you normally would!

So I added require 'postgres_ext/serializers' to my application.rb, made a small edit to a serializer to see if it worked:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  cached false

  attributes :id, :username, :location, :full_name

  def full_name
    "#{object.first_name} #{object.last_name}"
  end

  def full_name__sql
    "first_name || ' ' || email"
  end

end
```

Then I would run the following in my Rails console:

```
users = User.first(10)
ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(users, each_serializer: UserSerializer).to_json
```

But the __sql full name attribute was never shown and it didn't seem to pulling the data from postgres any differently than before.

And this is what my application.rb looks like:

```
# require 'postgres_ext/serializers' ### Doesn't work here

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

require 'postgres_ext/serializers'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Baller
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    # From: http://www.benfranklinlabs.com/where-to-put-rails-modules/
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) # add this line
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add exact error messages to your question. What exactly doesn't work and how do you know that?

Comment: @EugZol just added more detail to my post. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding this `require 'postgres_ext/serializers'` to the top of your `config/application.rb`. I guess this needs to be required before anything else, when it changes the Postgres drivers.

Update to answer your update:

```
def full_name__sql
  "first_name || ' ' || email"
end
```

should be:

```
def self.full_name__sql
 "first_name || ' ' || email"
end
```

From the docs:

> ... call by looking for a class method with the same name and the
>   suffix __sql ...

Comment: Yes, but I get an error when I include it at the very top: gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.0/lib/active_model_serializers.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveModel>': uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie (NameError) The earliest in the file that I can include it so it works is right after: require 'rails/all' Really appreciate any help on this!

Comment: so does it not work when you include it after rails/all ? I think after that should be the right place than.

Comment: When I include it after rails/all the console loads without an error, but it doesn't work in the sense that postgres_ext/serializers doesn't seem to be activated or connected.

Comment: Read my updated post. The method should be a class method.

Comment: the class method wasn't the problem as I've tried both ways... turns out that the variable being serialized needs to be of type ActiveRecord::Relation... and because users = User.first(10) returns an array of User objects and not an ActiveRecord::Relation, it doesn't trigger the code. So I changed my test to use User.where("id>100").limit(10) and it seems like it's trying to work, but now I get a new error "wrong number of arguements"... I'll open up a new SE post if I can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!